# Invoke JRE that is found in JDK

Tags: java, windows-10

I first installed JRE and Java applications ran fine. Later on, I installed JDK and found out that JRE is part of JDK as sub-directory. So, I removed the original JRE. This time, all the Java applications would not start. `JAVA_HOME` is set correctly to point to the JDK (I am able to compile Java code). The OS is Windows 10. Why is the JRE that is found in the JDK not getting invoked?

Comment: Not an answer, but you could try uninstalling and then reinstalling the JDK.

Comment: Did you reboot your system ? And check your Path variable (cmd --> echo %PATH%)

Comment: I guess, when you install the standalone JRE, it is registered in the Windows registry, unlike the JRE in the JDK, which is just there.

Comment: Why would it be invoked? For JDK installs, they're for complition purposes. If you want to use java to run applications so that it is used by windows automatically, you need to install/register a public jre for windows. JRE which comes part of JDK is a private one.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by private JRE?

Comment: Check if the JRE "bin" directory is on your "PATH" environment variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are installing JDK, you have an option to install "public JRE" - a separate installation that will be registered in Windows independently from JDK, added to the Windows registry, will be invoked when you type `java ...` in the command line and will be used by the programs relying just on JRE / `java` executable. The option to install "public JRE" is available in this step of JDK installation:

[image: JDK installation]

On the other hand, the `jre` folder inside the JDK distribution is a "private JRE" - not exposed to all your Windows programs, not registered in the Windows registry. If you install only the JDK without the "public JRE", `java` executable will not be found on the path. The "private JRE" will be useful for the programs depending on the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, which should be pointing to the root of the JDK.

I recommend installing a separate "public JRE", but if you want the `java` executable to be available in the console, add `%JAVA_HOME%/jre/bin` to your Windows `PATH` (or just `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` to use the `java` executable from the JDK itself). See [here](https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) for an instruction on how to modify your `PATH` variable. That assumes you have set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable - if you haven't, you can do it in the same configuration windows where you modify your `PATH`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Just wondering though ... why would it be necessary to have a public JRE if you are installing the full JDK?

Comment: Well.. it is not strictly *necessary* (see my last paragraph), I just guess they are used for two different purposes - JDK for development (additional tools), JRE just for launching Java programs (Windows: registry entries, browser plugin, automatic update). However, why JDK does not register the "private JRE" the same way a standalone, public JRE registers itself? I don't know.